# INCLUDE could not find load file while building with CMAKE

Tags: cmake, trilinos

I have been trying to build `zoltan2` with cmake but I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/cmake/tribits/core/package_arch/TribitsProjectImpl.cmake:61     
  (INCLUDE):
  INCLUDE could not find load file:
TribitsConstants
```

The `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` includes the directory in which `TribitsConstants` lives but still the error persists.

> CMAKE_MODULE_PATH='/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src;/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src/cmake;/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src/cmake/tribits/core/utils;/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src/cmake/tribits/core/package_arch/;/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src/cmake/tribits/core/config_tests;/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src/cmake/tribits/core/modules;/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src/cmake/tribits/core/installation'

Comment: Which directory contains the file `TribitsConstants.cmake`? The error is about inability of CMake to find this file.

Comment: It's in the same directory as the file `TribitsProjectImpl.cmake`

Comment: So, it is directory `/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/cmake/tribits/core/package_arch` which contains `TribitsConstants.cmake` file, right? But this directory is absent in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` list your show.

Comment: No it's there, look closely. It's the hiphen that's causing the line break.

Comment: The only directory in the list which contains `package_arch` component is `/home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/packages/zoltan2/src/cmake/tribits/core/package_arch/`. But the directory with the file is different: it contains `Trilinos-trilinos-release-12-12-1/` component before `cmake/`, not a `src/` one.